# Morphisms of affine varieties induced by algebras homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

(All the affine spaces $\mathbb A^n$ are considered $\Bbb A^n_k$, with $k=\bar k$ a field).

Let $C$ be the affine variety in $\Bbb A^2$ defined by $V(x^2+y^2-1)$. The morphisms (as ringed spaces) $\Bbb A^1\to C$ are in a functorial bijection with $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k[x,\sqrt{1-x^2}], k[t])$.

Every map sending $x$ to an element of $k$ is a homomorphism, and induces a constant morphism of $\Bbb A^1$ in $C$. Are there also non-constant morphisms? That is, are there (non-constant) polynomials $f\in k[t]$ such that $1-f^2$ is a square?

$k[t]$ is a factorial ring, where $1-f$ and $1+f$ are coprime, and $1-f^2$ splits in $(1-f)(1+f)$. So both $1+f,1-f$ should be squares, and here I am stuck. I couldn't even find an example of such an $f$, so I don't know what direction should I take. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: If $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}_2}$ and $i$ is a solution of $X^2 + 1 = 0$ in $k$, take $f = i t$. Then $1-f^2 = 1+t^2 = (1+t)^2$.

Comment: Thank you, are there example also in characteristic $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nonconstant solution in characteristic 0. Let us assume there exists $g \in k[t]$ such that $1-f^2 = g^2$. Let $i$ be a solution of $X^2 + 1= 0$ in $k$ and set $h = if$. Then $1 = g^2 - h^2 = (g-h)(g+h)$. Thus, $g-h$ and $g+h$ are invertible. So $g+h$ is an element of $k^{\star}$. But in characteristic zero, we have
$$ \max\{\mathrm{deg}(g-h),\mathrm{deg}(g+h)\} \geqslant \max\{\mathrm{deg}\, g, \mathrm{deg}\, h\} $$
So $\mathrm{deg}(h) = 0$ and $f$ has to be constant.

Comment: Your argument has a little bit of a hole - it's not necessarily true that $\deg(g+h)\geq \max(\deg g, \deg h)$ as $g=x+1$, $h=-x$ show. What is true is that if $2\neq 0$, as $(g+h)+(g-h)=2g\in k$, we get $g\in k$ and similarly $h\in k$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks ;) I fixed my answer.